# Excel VBA Time Format as decimal with Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, time, combobox, format

Very basic, and very annoying, I have searched solution for many hours with no help...

Problem: I'm populating Combobox from named range, range is list of times (formatted as time :-), Combo seems fine, drop-down shows my times as they should be, but when selected time is formatted as a decimal number...

[image]

Here is the code (ripped down to bare minimum):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBoxTime.RowSource = "Help!Time" 
End Sub
```

"Help" is name of worksheet containing named range "Time"I have tried formatting different ways with no luck...

```
ComboBoxTime = Format(ComboBoxTime, "hhmm")
```

Here is link to sample. http://www.equstom.fi/dateproblem.html

(And yes I need to populate from named range, instead for each loop, and I will set .value with code, Whole document is actually quite complex, but I included just The problem part...)

Comment: Your link http://www.equstom.fi/dateproblem.html is broken

Comment: Sorry, here it is http://www.equstom.fi/dateproblem.xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is named range I'm using, when values are formatted as time it won't work. I got it to work if values were Text! Problem has something to do with excel being in Finnish and VBA in english...
I added second column next to range which copies text values to this named second range formatted as time. Quick and Dirty! (Thanks for your input Belisarius)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
With ComboBox1
  .Value = Format(.Value, "hh:mm:ss AMPM")

End With
End Sub
```

HTH!

**Edit** 
This is what I see when leaving your combo. The time display works OK.

[image]

**Edit 2**

Found the error "invalid property":

You must set "Match Requiered" to FALSE in the combo box. If you consider that it should be "TRUE" you will have to validate by hand ...

Comment: Doesn't work... And the -Value should be formated with UserForm_Initialize not with Change...

Comment: @Mika Works in my machine ... It MUST be formated with Change. Initialize only formats the list, not the upper box

Comment: @Mika Seems your WS has some problem with the library references. The standard VBA **Format** function **does not work** within your WS!!

Comment: @Mika Found the problem. At least in my machine deactivating the reference for the Outlook DLL restores normality, and the above code runs OK.

Comment: :-) Sorry the link was .html, again should be .xlsm http://www.equstom.fi/dateproblem2.xlsm There isn't any reference to outlook library in this new workbook, but the problem remains (And thak you for taking your time to solve this!)

Comment: @Mika your second workbook runs almost ok in my machine. At closing displays "invalid property value", but the time display is OK.

Comment: @Mika Sorry, need to get some sleep (5 AM here). Post your advance and I'll try to continue tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Belisarius, I try different formats... get some sleep.

Comment: @Mika Last try ... see if your local (.fi) format is not interfering with the "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: No, I can use english time formats, works fine with rest of my application. The problem is named range I'm using, when values are formatted as time it won't work. I got it to work if values were Text! But this isn't really a solution, is it?

Comment: @Mika Anything that works is a solution :) So I'd copy the source range to a hidden one as text upon initialization and then use that. I really don't know why it is not working on your machine, but an extensive check of the Windows and Excel config options is not appropriate in this question. You may open another question "Why my combobox time format does not work" and tag it under Windows and Excel to get a broader audience.